# How to handle has-one relation with polymorphic relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Media');
    }
}

class Media extends Model
{
    public function mediable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'mediable');
    }
}

class Image extends Model
{
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'mediable');
    }
}
```

- Each game will have one media type which are ( Video ) or ( Image ).

Questions:

- When I delete a game I want to delete all of its relations in
  database.. how to do that?
- How can I create a media ( video or image ) from **Game** model ?
  something like Game()->media()->createVideo()...
- How can I access some a game's media info easily ?

Comment: Do you really need a model for media or is that an unnecessary abstraction?  You lose out on FK integrity with this type of polymorphic relationship, so you'd have to handle deletions in your application or with some custom trigger.

Comment: Yes, because a game will have only-one of these media types ( video or image or a an article .. etc ) I think this is the perfect scenario to use polymorphic relationship..

Comment: That's not what I asked.  I asked if the model was necessary.  Could you just have media as a polymorphic relationship inside of Game?

Comment: a game will have its fields ( title - desc - rating etc ) and also other relations like category .. it seems better for me to add a media model as standalone? yes?

Comment: Also I added the media model because a game must have only-one media type ( Video or Image ) .. If I removed the media model how can I tell the game model to have a Video OR a an Image media ?

Comment: The same way you're doing it on the media table.  games.media_type and games.media_id

Comment: so I would remove media model and do polymorphic relations on the game model ? and that will have the same result?